# Can I use getSupportFragmentManager() to create child fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-nested-fragment

I read this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

specifically I read,

> The Android Support Library also now supports nested fragments, so you can implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.

So I thought you could use getSupportFragmentManager() to create nested fragments and I used it in my app and, at first, everything seemed fine. But now some weird stuff is happening such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091727/what-exactly-happens-when-android-recreates-my-app-on-an-orientation-change-usin) so maybe I was wrong.

edit: The weird stuff was actually a different issue that I figured out. getSupportFragmentManager() seems to work fine when creating child fragments. Only thing weird that happens is the child fragment is not destroyed if you hit the back button. But it gets destroyed when you attempt to recreate it again.

Answer (score 4):

> So I thought you could use getSupportFragmentManager() to create nested fragments

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to create fragments that are immediate children of the activity.

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` on the fragment to create fragments that are immediate children of that fragment.